# document.activeElement.href not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `document.activeElement.href` for get target location of clicked tag. Its worked property in firefox, but not working in chrome.

I want to get `"href"` location of a clicked(active) element in other function outside of it.

like this:

```
function animate() {
    alert(document.activeElement.href); //not working in chrome
});
```

Thanks alot

EDIT :
Remember i dont want to use "this" or $(this) because it doesn't work in a function outside of the element. 
I know i can use `onclick="...."` then use `"$(this)"` for each element but i dont want this.

My question is simple:

> can i get clicked(active) elementID in a function outside of it?
>   (Except in firefox)

Comment: @Liam, your link says `activeElement` is supported by Chrome 2 and later (MDN [says the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement), the accepted answer saying Chrome 9+ is apparently a mistake).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, sorry must of misread it. My bad

Comment: @Nader, is there any chance you set the focus to another element before calling `animate()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) from [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var elm = e.target;
    if (elm && elm.nodeType === 1 && elm.nodeName === 'A') {
        alert(elm.href);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for Vanilla JS, the most powerful JS of all! Even jQuery uses it! :D

Comment: @Kolink, but is `nodeName` guaranteed to return an uppercase element name on all implementations? I would apply `toUpperCase()` to be sure, but using a non-vanilla library would hide that from me in the first place ;)

Comment: `nodeName` is the uppercase name of the tag (on element nodes, which has been established with `nodeType===1`), that's just how it's defined.

Comment: @Kolink, for [known HTML (not XML) elements](http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/), yes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi In what browser is `a` an unknown HTML element? ;)

Comment: Thanks Worked Perfectly, this is all i needed :) you are great Vanilla JS.
We can get id by add this to your code : 
`elm.id` and get href location without http://~~ with this `$('#'+elm.id).attr('href');`

Answer (score 2):

That element would be focused then

```
$("a:focus").prop("href")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kYJ3n/

Comment: Good idea, given `:focus` is explicitly documented as not being equivalent to `$(document.activeElement)`.

Comment: Thanks but its not worked ! u can use alert($("a:focus").prop("href")); and see not working in chrome and safari ;)

Comment: @Nader simply add tabindex to your element ;) [http://jsfiddle.net/kYJ3n/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/kYJ3n/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with jQuery

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
      alert($(this).attr('href'));
 });
```

this does though depend on when you actually call your event. You haven't specified this so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, really why? How could I guarantee that jquery was loaded without the ready?

Comment: @Liam, `document` always exists, and `on()` delegates the event to it. That kind of binding will work even if the DOM is not ready (but not if jQuery is not loaded, of course).

Comment: If jQuery is not loaded it will obviously fail in any case - `$` won't be defined. The only case where a ready wrapper is necessary if you use selectors and don't know if the selected elements have already been processed (e.g. because the `<script>` tag comes before the related element in the HTML DOM tree which hasn't been fully parsed/loaded at this point)

Comment: the docs say *"so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code"* http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Liam, you have to understand what happens under the hood. The goal of `ready()` is to avoid trying to match an element that the browser has yet to parse. `document` does not have to be parsed and always exists. Using event delegation to `document` allows to match any element *at the time the event occurs* instead of *at page load* (that's pretty much the basis of event delegation), so applying `on()` to `$(document)` will always work as expected even if the DOM is not ready, provided jQuery was loaded before the call to `$()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, makes sense. Suppose I'm still in the "pre-on" mindset where everything, pretty much, had a selector. Everyday's a school day...!